# How to correctly structure a java project

Tags: standards

What is technically the correct way in going about structuring a java or android project with regards to different components?

Say i have the Database, Networking and View components. Should i put each one in a new package within the src folder and then all their classes within those packages?

Or are you meant to just bang all of the classes in the default package?

I just want to know whats the standard or correct way to go about organizing the project so that it is easily navigable.

Comment: I always use the standards used by the language/dialect itself. It makes the most sense to me. Though you are free to do what you want.

Comment: and those standards are ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much answered you own question: namely how you want it; Easily navigable is a subjective requirement. It depends on how you like it.

Of course there are standards on how to do this and certain folders are required and if you are new I can surely advise to use the recommended structure by android. Following recommended file structure is conventionally a good idea.

Maybe this link can help you: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Also to add, I personally prefer to group different parts of the application in different packages; so separate packages for view, model, DAO, database, etc.

Comment: So different packages it is. And I see that you can make library projects. This could be good for the networking API etc